A differential equation of the form $x''+a^2 x=0$ does not lead to solutions involving sine and cosine
I want to solve the following equation in Mathematica:
kx = n Pi
ky = (m Pi)/3
ODEt = T''[t] == -(kx^2 + ky^2) T[t]

So, I write:
solT = DSolve[ODEt, T[t], t]

This gives me the following answer:
{{T[t] -> E^(1/3 Sqrt[-m^2 - 9 n^2] π t) C[1] + E^(-(1/3) Sqrt[-m^2 - 9 n^2] π t) C[2]}}

One would expect a solution involving sine and cosine. Instead, I got square roots with negative radicands. How can I get the usual solution?
I understand that the answer from Mathematica is equivalent to the one I want, I just need a way to directly obtain the result in the desired form.

it is not possible what you show. There is no m and no n in your input. How did they show in the solution? As for the title of you question, when I type DSolve[x''[t]+a^2*x[t]==0,x[t],t] mathematica gives {{x[t] -> C[1]*Cos[a*t] + C[2]*Sin[a*t]}} which is correct.

solT = DSolve[ODEt, T[t], t, Assumptions -> {kx > 0, ky > 0}] // ExpToTrig // Simplify

@Nasser, Excuse me. I forgot to write that kx = n Pi and ky = (m Pi)/3. I corrected it.

@JieZhu , If I use ExpToTrig, I end up with a solution involving hyperbolic sine and cosine ((C[1] + C[2]) Cosh[1/3 Sqrt[-m^2 - 9 n^2] π t] + (C[1] - C[2]) Sinh[    1/3 Sqrt[-m^2 - 9 n^2] π t]). I want a solution in the usual form $a cos(wt)+b sin(wt).

kx=n Pi
ky=(m Pi)/3
ode=T''[t]==-(kx^2+ky^2) T[t]
sol=DSolveValue[ODEt,T[t],t]
sol=Expand[Assuming[kx^2+ky^2>0,Simplify[sol]]]


sol = ExpToTrig[sol]


sol=Simplify[sol,{C[1]+I*C[1]==C[3],C[2]-I*C[2]==C[4]}]


 sol /. {(C[1] + C[2]) -> C[3], I  (C[1] - C[2]) -> C[4]}


But a short cut method is this:
kx=n Pi
ky=(m Pi)/3
ode=T''[t]==-(kx^2+ky^2) T[t]
ode=ode/.(-kx^2-ky^2)->-a^2;


Now solve the above and substitute back
sol=DSolveValue[ode,T[t],t];
sol/.a->-Sqrt[(-kx^2-ky^2)]



It is simpler to substitute ./{a->1/3Sqrt[m^2+9n^2]Pi t} into the solution you have demonstrated in the comments above.

@Nasser Thank you very much for the interest you showed and the response you gave!!! How do you explain the fact of this strange behavior of Mathematica?

@KώσταςΚούδας Mathematica just gives generic solution which is also correct. Fine tuning each solution to the most optimal form might not be possible each time and in each case.

@Nasser ,Thank you very much for your answer. Have a great day!

I think the solution you obtained from Mathematica is indeed correct but presented in an exponential form. To obtain the solution in terms of sine and cosine functions, you can use the fact that the general solution to a second-order linear homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients can be written using complex exponentials, which can be converted to sine and cosine using Euler's formula.Here is an attempt for improved mathematica code:
(*Define constants*)kx = n Pi;
ky = (m Pi)/3;

(*Define the differential equation*)
ODEt = T''[t] == -((kx^2 + ky^2) T[t]);

(*Solve the differential equation*)
solT = DSolve[ODEt, T[t], t]

(*Convert the solution to trigonometric form*)
solTTrig = solT /. {E^(a_ t) :> Cosh[a t] + Sinh[a t]};

(*Extract the solution from the rule*)
Tsol = T[t] /. solTTrig[[1]]

(*Convert hyperbolic functions to trigonometric functions using \
imaginary arguments*)
TsolTrig = Tsol /. {Cosh[a_] :> Cos[I a], Sinh[a_] :> Sin[I a]/I};

(*Simplify the expression*)
TsolTrigSimplified = Simplify[TsolTrig]



Thank you very much for your response. I will look into your solution immediately.
